# Android - GLSurface, errror while closing

Tags: android, canvas, glsurfaceview

Every time I occur an error while I close the app. I dont know why? Its occur only on 2.3.7.
Everything working fine on 3.2 and 4

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.onDetachedFromWindow(GLSurfaceView.java:533)
at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:6190)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1162)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1162)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1162)
at android.view.ViewRoot.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRoot.java:1751)
at android.view.ViewRoot.doDie(ViewRoot.java:2766)
at android.view.ViewRoot.die(ViewRoot.java:2736)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:218)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeViewImmediate(Window.java:477)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2822)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:972)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly a duplicate of this: [GLSurfaceView.onDetachedFromWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785182/glsurfaceview-ondetachedfromwindow)

Is the game actually working and running when you close the window? In the other question sounds like they never attached the renderer, but I'm not sure if that's true in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
Because on 2.3 the GLSurfaceView.onDetachedFromWindow method didn't do nullpointer protection;However this method did nullpointer protection on other version above 2.3.

protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
  super.onDetachedFromWindow();
  mGLThread.requestExitAndWait();
}

the solution is that set a render for your GLSurfaceView object like below:
mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(new MyRenderer());

mGLThread is init in setRenderer() method;the code is below:

    public void setRenderer(Renderer renderer) {
        checkRenderThreadState();
        if (mEGLConfigChooser == null) {
            mEGLConfigChooser = new SimpleEGLConfigChooser(true);
        }
        if (mEGLContextFactory == null) {
            mEGLContextFactory = new DefaultContextFactory();
        }
        if (mEGLWindowSurfaceFactory == null) {
            mEGLWindowSurfaceFactory = new DefaultWindowSurfaceFactory();
        }
        mRenderer = renderer;
        mGLThread = new GLThread(mThisWeakRef);
        mGLThread.start();
    }
so if you have set a renderer on 2.3,you would not met the nullpointer exception;Hope this could help you.
```